# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to validate login form using a `SqlDataReader`, but I get a syntax error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '='

I have reviewed my code and don't seem to detect the above error. Please assist.

This is my code:

```
string btnString = "SELECT userName, passWord, FacultyId, StudentId FROM LOGIN";
btnString += "WHERE(userName=@name) AND (passWord=@word)";

SqlCommand cc = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader sr;

cc.Connection = sqlConn;
cc.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cc.CommandText = btnString;

cc.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtUserName.Text;
cc.Parameters.Add("@word", SqlDbType.Char, 8).Value = txtPassWord.Text;

sr = cc.ExecuteReader();

if (sr.HasRows == true)
{
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Login is successful!')</script>");
}
```

The error is displayed at

```
sr = cc.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a space

```
 btnString += " WHERE(userName=@name) AND (passWord=@word)";
```

Comment: You're welcome. Check about multiline strings in @Konstantin Spirin answer

Answer (score 1):

Your missing a space in the commandtext.

```
string btnString = "SELECT userName, passWord, FacultyId, StudentId FROM LOGIN";
btnString += " WHERE(userName=@name) AND (passWord=@word)";
```

Should do it

Answer (score 1):

A space is missing. You can use multiline strings instead of concatenation to avoid such problems in future (note `@` before the `"`):

```
string btnString = @"
    SELECT userName, passWord, FacultyId, StudentId FROM LOGIN
    WHERE(userName=@name) AND (passWord=@word)";
```

You can read more about strings [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx).